# How do I create a popup window for Twitter authorization?

Tags: oauth, twitter, blackberry-playbook, blackberry-webworks

I want to create a Blackberry Playbook webworks app that links to twitter using an oauth library. How do I create a popup window from within the app using Javascript to display the Twitter authorization page?

It doesn't seem that I can use an iframe, as Twitter's code seems to check if it's running from an iframe, from what I've read.

Comment: Related trivia: the possibility of using iframe is disabled due to the risk of click-jacking. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clickjacking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't seem to be possible, but via [this question](http://www.google.com/url?q=http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-and-WebWorks-Development/Has-Anyone-Implemented-an-OAuth-Flow-in-a-Playbook-WebWorks/td-p/951143&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNGCjrNJ2b0qhrwMznhk4wMWrRGZ2A) I found an extension from [polarmobile](https://github.com/polarmobile/blackberry.polarmobile.childbrowser) that does the job. There's also an app called [Lemma](http://lemmaforplaybook.com/) that demonstrates how to use it.